# Node JS get 404 error not found when i try to access to a js file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to access a `js` file from my `index.html` file, but I'm getting this error:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/js/script.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

I know there are several posts about this issue but I still can't find a solution.

So here is my folder structure:

```
Game
|-- Client
|   |--Js
|      |--script.js
|
|-- Server
    |-- server.js
```

This is the few lines in my `server.js`:

```js
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
app.use("/js", express.static('./client/js/'));
```

And this is a part of my `index.html`:

```html
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
```

Comment: your path handles `/js` but you are requesting `js/script.js`

Comment: so what? how can i fix it?

Comment: where is the folder structure does index.html sit?

Comment: ```<script src="/script.js"></script>``` it will work.

Comment: @MuhammadSaquibShaikh It doesn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are telling your express server to serve the folder 'Server/client/js' at route 'localhost:3000/js'.

If your folder structure is what you say it is, then you would get this error, since there is no such folder.

The most straightforward way of fixing this would be to move your client folder into your Server folder and change your static folder destination to './Client/js'.